# Taylor's Remainder

Tags: taylor-expansion

what is the maximum error when approximating $e^{x}$ by $1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}$ for $|x|<1$?

Answer for this is $\frac{e}{6}$.
Can anyone teach me the working for this question, please?

Answer (score 1):

Taylor remainder for $n$th degree polynomial= $\displaystyle \frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^n$ for some $c$ between $x_0$ and $x$.

The Taylor remainder $\displaystyle \frac{e^c}{6}x^3$ has a supremum of $\displaystyle \frac{e}{6}$ when $c=x=1$.

Comment: I fixed a typo in your formula for the remainder. Still, you may want to explain what $x_0$ is.

Comment: $x_0=0$ in this case. A Taylor series around $x_0$ has terms of the form $c_i(x-x_0)^i$.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to use:

$$\displaystyle |R_n(x)| \le \frac{M_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|x-a|^{n+1}$$

where:

$\displaystyle R_n(x) = f(x) -T_n(x)$ is the remainder term and $T_n(x)$ is the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ for $f(x)$, centered at $x = a$.

For this problem, we have, for $f(x) = e^x$:

$$\displaystyle T_2(x) = f(0) + f'(0)(x-0) + \frac{f''(0)}{2}(x-0)^2  = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}$$

We also have: $f'''(x) = e^x$, so

Max $\displaystyle |f'''(x)|$ on $-1 \le x \le 1$ occurs on the endpoints, that is $x = \pm 1$, so:

$$\displaystyle M_3 = \max_{-1 \le x \le 1} |f'''(x)| = e^1$$

So, the upper error bound is given by:

$$\displaystyle |f(x) -T_2(x)| = |R_2(x)| \le \frac{M_3}{3!}|x-0|^3 = \frac{e}{6}|1|^3 = \frac{e}{6}$$

Comment: Nice! + 1 (I'll get your others in an hour or so!!)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks and hope you are having a great Sunday!

Answer (score 1):

You are computing an upper bound on the error, not the maximum (well, supremum) error.

The maximum error can be computed as follows:

Let $f(x) = e^x-(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2})$. Then $f'(x) = e^x-(1+x)$, with $f'(0) = 0$. Since $f''(x) = e^x-1$, we have $f''(x) <0$ for $x <0$, and $f''(x) >0$ for $x>0$. It follows that $f'$ is non-negative on $[-1,1]$. Hence the extrema of $f$ can only occur at $\{-1,0,+1\}$.

We have $f(-1) = e^{-1} - \frac{1}{2}$, $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = e-\frac{5}{2}$. It is easy to check that $f(-1)<0, f(1)>0$, and by noting that $x^2-\frac{x}{2}-1 >0$ for all $x$, we can verify that $|f(-1)| < f(1)$.

Hence $\max_{|x|\le 1} f(x) = e-\frac{5}{2}$ (which is less than $\frac{e}{6}$).